# Retain the page when Refresh the Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an 3 divs and 1 Iframe. The Iframe is in `<div id="maincontent">`. When refresh it goes back to the default.php. What I want to is to retain the page when refresh the Iframe. For i.e I click link3 and refresh it, it should not back to the default.php. Any help please.

```
<div id="framecontentLeft">
<div class="innertube">
<a href="link1.php" target="contents">LINK1</a><br/>
<a href="link2.php" target="contents">LINK2</a><br/>
<a href="link3.php" target="contents">LINK3</a><br/>
<a href="link4.php" target="contents">LINK4</a><br/>
</div>
</div>

<div id="framecontentTop">
<div class="innertube">

<img src="images/header.jpg"/> 

</div>
</div>


<div id="maincontent">
<div class="innertube">

<iframe name="contents" src="default.php" id="iframe"></iframe>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an event listener to the links that `event.preventDefault()`s so the page doesn't change and modify the `src` attribute of the iframe with the `href` of the clicked link.

Comment: @ultraviol3tlux Pardon me. But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using jQuery, it'd go a little something like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e){

    // This stops the page from refreshing
    e.preventDefault();

    // This passes the target page from the link into the iframe
    $('iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));

});
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: But how the other page that not in href? For i.e in link1 there's a link to another page?

Answer (score 0):

Modify html as shown below

```
<div id="framecontentLeft">
<div class="innertube">
<a onclick="SetPage('link1.php','contents');return false;">LINK1</a><br/>
<a onclick="SetPage('link2.php','contents');return false;">LINK2</a><br/>
<a onclick="SetPage('link3.php','contents');return false;">LINK3</a><br/>
<a onclick="SetPage('link4.php','contents');return false;">LINK4</a><br/>
</div>
</div>
```

Add following javascript in script tag

```
function SetPage(linkUrl, target) {
  document.getElementById(target).src = linkUrl;
}
```

Comment: why I can't click the href?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this...

```
<head>
<meta http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Pragma" Content="no-cache">
<meta http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
</head>
```

It will force no cache checks.